# Query Lookup Relationship With SOQL Not Working

Tags: soql, lookup, sobject, relationships

I have a SalesForce custom object named `Loan__c` which has a Lookup field called `LoanLead__c` and I'm trying to query that relationship with SOQL but I'm getting an error when I run the query `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM LoanLeads__r) FROM Loan__c` on the object in the developer console query editor.

I've confirmed the Object API name of the related `LoanLeads` table is indeed `LoanLead__c` and I have tried modifying the query to select from the `LoanLead__r` table and a few others, but I get the same error.

The error I'm getting is:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM LoanLeads__r) FROM Loan__c
                           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
Didn't understand relationship 'LoanLeads__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

This is what the field settings are for the lookup field:
[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - everything I've read says this should work and it does work with other lookup fields on this same table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Loan__c has a lookup to LoanLead__c then LoanLead__c is the parent. Meaning the query would be Select Id, (select Id from Loans__r) from LoanLead__c. Be sure the relation name is Loans for this to work

Comment: Yeah, that is what ended up working. `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Loans__r) FROM LoanLead__c` was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Child Relationship Name is `Loans`, so it should be `Loans__r`, not `LoanLeads__r`.

Comment: Well, not only that but I didn't realize the relationship was from `LoanLead__c` to `Loans__c` instead of the other way around.

What ended up working is `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Loans__r) FROM LoanLead__c` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Noges suggested, the parent table was actually the `LoanLead__c` table and not `Loan__c` so what ended up working for me was `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Loans__r) FROM LoanLead__c` and also `SELECT Id, LoanLead__r.Id FROM Loan__c`.

Answer (score 0):

When we query child object in sub-query then we use **Child Relationship Name**. If relationship is custom then we need to append suffix `__r`.

```
Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From Contacts__r) from Account
Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From Contacts) from Account
```

When we query parent object in that case we use field name with suffix `__r` instead of `__c`.

```
Select Id, Name, Account.Name, Custom_Account__r.Name From Contact
```

**Custom Relationship**
[image: Field with Custom Relationship]

**Standard Relationship**
[image: Field with Standard Relationship]

I hope this will help you.